# Wordpress nginx map value not working in cloudpanel.io

Tags: wordpress, nginx, nginx-module

I want to set up [WordPress Multisite Subdirectory rules](https://wordpress.org/support/article/nginx/#wordpress-multisite-subdirectory-rules) but i get this error "Vhost is not valid."

```
map $uri $blogname{
~^(?P/[^/]+/)files/(.*) $blogpath ;
}

map $blogname $blogid{
default -999;
include /var/www/html/wp-content/uploads/nginx-helper/map.conf;
}
server { ...
```

thx :)

Answer (score 0):

According to [this blog](https://tonyteaches.tech/wordpress-multisite-nginx/). You need to add this crucial part into your `server`:

```
        # Rewrite requests to /wp-.* on subdirectory installs.
        if (!-e $request_filename) {
                rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;
                rewrite ^/[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+(/wp-.*) $1 last;
                rewrite ^/[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+(/.*\.php)$ $1 last;
        }
```